# how to add data with date based on condition?

Tags: php

Following is my php code which return date with amount until the condition is false :

```
<?php
$paid = 2000;
$monthly = 750;
$date_array = array("2016-07", "2016-09");
$bill_paid_array =  array(750, 600);

$x=0;
do {

    $found = false;
    while (!$found) {
        $date = date('2016'.'-'.'07'.'-d');
        $time = strtotime($date);
        $bill_month = date("Y-m", strtotime( ($x++)." month", $time));
        $found = !in_array($bill_month,$date_array) ;
    }

    echo date($bill_month."-d") . "=> $monthly<br/>\n";

    $paid -= $monthly;
    if ($paid < $monthly) {
        $monthly = $paid;
    }
} while ($paid > 0);
```

**Return Data :**

```
2016-08-16=> 750
2016-10-16=> 750
2016-11-16=> 500
```

**How it's working :**

This code is checking which monthly bill user paid already from starting date. If the month exist then next month is showing until condition is false.

Now for : e.g: starting date is : `2016-07-01` and user already paid `2016-07` and `2016-09` month bill (see $date_array)

Now user is paying `2000` and his bill amount is `750`. So that code is showing following date with amount.

**Return Data :**

```
2016-08-16=> 750
2016-10-16=> 750
2016-11-16=> 500
```

**What I want now**

Now if I paid a new bill `750`again then according to above code this line : `date($bill_month."-d") . "=> $monthly<br/>\n";` will show me `2016-12-16` date: But which I don't want. I want to show : `2016-11-16` with `250` and `2016-12-16` with `500`.

**Note : I have $bill_paid_array for each month**

**Update :**

```
$allBillMonth = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT YEAR(bill_month) AS bill_year, MONTH(bill_month) AS bill_month, pay_amount FROM clients_pay_bill WHERE client_id = '$client_id' AND uid = '$uid' ");

$date_array = array();
$pay_amount_array = array();

while( $fetchAllBillMonth = mysqli_fetch_array($allBillMonth) ) {
    $year = $fetchAllBillMonth['bill_year'];
    $month = $fetchAllBillMonth['bill_month'];
    $date_array[] = "$year-$month";
    if($monthly_bill != $fetchAllBillMonth['pay_amount']) {
        $flag = 0;
    } else {
        $flag =1;
    }

    $db_paid_amount = $fetchAllBillMonth['pay_amount'];
    $pay_amount_array[] = "$year-$month => [$db_paid_amount, $flag]";
}
```

**Output :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2016-8 => [750.00, 1]
    [1] => 2016-9 => [750.00, 1]
    [2] => 2016-10 => [700.00, 0]
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this one, I modified the $bill_paid_array, if you have any question I will explain

```
<?php
$paid = 2000;
$monthly = 750;
$date_array = array("2016-07", "2016-09");
$bill_paid_array =  array("2016-07" => [750,1], "2016-09" => [600,0]);

$is_full_amount = 1;
$previous_month = 0;
$x=0;

do {

$found = false;
while (!$found) {
    $date = date('2016'.'-'.'07'.'-d');
    $time = strtotime($date);
    $bill_month = date("Y-m", strtotime( ($x++)." month", $time));
    if (in_array($bill_month,$date_array)){
        if ($bill_paid_array["$bill_month"][1] == 0){
            $found = true;
            $previous_month = $monthly -$bill_paid_array["$bill_month"][0];
        }
    }else
        $found = !in_array($bill_month,$date_array) ;

}
if ($previous_month >0){
    echo date($bill_month."-d") . "=> $previous_month<br/>\n";
    $paid -= $previous_month;
    $previous_month = 0;
    $bill_paid_array["$bill_month"][1] = 1;
    $bill_paid_array["$bill_month"][0] =  $monthly;

}else {
    echo date($bill_month."-d") . "=> $monthly<br/>\n";
    $date_array[]=$bill_month;
    $bill_paid_array[$bill_month] = [$monthly,$is_full_amount];
    $paid -= $monthly;

}

if ($paid < $monthly) {
    $monthly = $paid;
    $is_full_amount = 0;
}
} while ($paid > 0);
```

Hope it will work as you want :)

Comment: Ok. Let me try it.

Comment: It's return same output like my one.

Comment: returning => 2016-08-16=> 750,  2016-10-16=> 750, 2016-11-16=> 500 but should return => 2016-08-16=> 750, 2016-09-16=>150,  2016-10-16=> 750, 2016-11-16=> 350

Comment: this depends on your $monthly value

Comment: I made one modification on the code please check it now

Comment: Ok.  I am getting this array `$bill_paid_array` from database. So now should I return this array like your given one ?

Comment: yes it should contain the month as a key and two values ([0] the paid amount,[1] flag that determines if it was fully paid or not)

Comment: Well, I have updated my questions: Now check the output array. will it be working then ?

Comment: Okey. got the desire array :)

Comment: if it worked fine it helps to vote up and accept the answer for the question, as you see I am new at this website :)

Comment: somehow it's showing me incorrect date. My `$bill_paid_array` is return this output : Array
(
    [2016-8] => [750.00, 1]
    [2016-9] => [750.00, 1]
    [2016-10] => [700.00, 0]
)

Comment: No I mean I am showing this array . Is it wrong output ?

Comment: As I see no it is true, the first two months 750 is paid so the flag is 1, the last month 700 is paid so the flag is 0

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
while (!$var) {
    $date = date('2016'.'-'.'07'.'-d');
    $time = strtotime($date);
    $bill_month = date("Y-m", strtotime( ($x++)." month", $time));
    if (in_array($bill_month,$date_array)){
        if ($bill_paid_array["$bill_month"][1] == 0){
            $found = true;
            $previous_month = $monthly -$bill_paid_array["$bill_month"][0];
        }
    }else
        $found = !in_array($bill_month,$date_array) ;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$paid = 2000;
$monthly = 750;
$date_array = array("2016-07", "2016-09");
$bill_paid_array =  array("2016-07" => [750,1], "2016-09" => [600,1]);

$is_full_amount = 1;
$previous_month = 0;
$x=0;

do {

$found = false;
while (!$found) {
    $date = date('2016'.'-'.'07'.'-d');
    $time = strtotime($date);
    $bill_month = date("Y-m", strtotime( ($x++)." month", $time));
    if (in_array($bill_month,$date_array)){
        if ($bill_paid_array["$bill_month"][1] == 0){
            $found = true;
            $previous_month = $monthly -$bill_paid_array["$bill_month"][0];
        }
    }else
        $found = !in_array($bill_month,$date_array) ;

}
if ($previous_month >0){
    echo date($bill_month."-d") . "=> $previous_month<br/>\n";
    $paid -= $previous_month;
    $previous_month = 0;
    $bill_paid_array["$bill_month"][1] = 1;
    $bill_paid_array["$bill_month"][0] =  $monthly;

}else {
    echo date($bill_month."-d") . "=> $monthly<br/>\n";
    $date_array[]=$bill_month;
    $bill_paid_array[$bill_month] = [$monthly,$is_full_amount];
    $paid -= $monthly;

}

} while ($paid > 0);
```